# jquery animation tray

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

please have a look [at an example here](http://cornerstonekilts.com/test/test.php).

I am trying to animate it so that the grey tray slides down but the 'more' tab should move down at the same time. I can't figure it out. Can someone help me? What am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: please share your html so we can help you

Comment: Most likely the correct answer is to properly embed that div so it moves on its own. Please post some working sample code to www.jsfiddle.net, save it and post the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add it's own animation. Or correctly nest it inside the #tray.

```
$('.pull').click(function(){
  $("#tray").hide("slide", { direction: "down"}, 3000);
  $('.pull').animate({'top':'120px'});
});
```

Comment: worked perfecty - thanks again (and sorry for the delay in coming back!)